# Word for high volume but low information density communication

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a single word to describe a communication style that is high volume, low information density that is more formal than windbag.

Loquacious is the best I've come up with so far but I don't feel like it captures the low information density by itself.

Basically trying to find a an eloquent way to capture Homer's "You take forever to say nothing."

Comment: Please  include a sample sentence showing how the word is to be  used per the SWR tag.

Comment: 'Long winded' is a bit more formal than 'windbag' -- "He gave a long winded explanation."

Comment: See also [What is a word to describe inefficient communication?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321485/what-is-a-word-to-describe-inefficient-communication/321572#321572), and obviously the 'duplicate' of the cited duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

***verbiage***, or ***verbose***

In the Western world it refers to excess words and possibly garbage, but in other parts of the world it just means "words".

> language that is very complicated and contains a lot of unnecessary words:

[Cambridge online](http://language%20that%20is%20very%20complicated%20and%20contains%20a%20lot%20of%20unnecessary%20words:)

Answer (score 0):

Describe a communication style

Chatty is a good word if less than formal. It's hard to beat *Loquacious* any day.

It's important to note that information density is best at about 50%. New data must be mixed with old ideas. These are the old words carrying the new ideas that language is so good at.

To describe the information density being a bit lean I would suggest other realms of description. Lean, empty, devoid come to mind. But an overly wordy communication style for this would be diffuse, lengthy, rambling, tedious or windy.